# Build an array into redux state by combining an action payload with an array index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

(skip to 'Query Reducer file' heading for the crux of the matter.)

I am in the early stages of designing an email builder. 
The core functionality that I am trying to write right now is that on click, the App is to take pre-made rows and embed them into a pre-made structure to make a module and then I'll later render the completed module to the DOM.

I am building it so that the rows that are embedded to a structure when rendering a module to the DOM will be determined by the state of a query string.

The query string will be built by buttons which will correspond to objects in an array storing row components(react components).

Then all I need to do is to nest the query string state into the structures.

This stage is nearly ready but I am unsure how to tie up the query string reducer to combine the payload with the id's of the row array.

### App file

This is imported, connected to the store and rendered to the DOM in an index file. **The main part to take away is that the button sends a parameter to queryAction**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { queryAction } from './store/actions/queryAction.js';
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    queryString: state.queryReducer
  }
}
const matchDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({ queryAction: queryAction }, dispatch)
}
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { queryString } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {console.log('stored query string = ' + queryString)}
        <button onClick={() => this.props.queryAction('1')}> Dispatch query string </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(App);
```

### Query Action file

Moves the **parameter** on to a **matching reducer** (queryReducer)

```
export const queryAction = (i) => {
    console.log('/action');
    console.log('payload = '+ i);
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_QUERY',
        payload: i
    }
};
```

### Row Reducer file

Here the imported head, body, btn and img components are JSX'ified email row components which I use to build an array that I can call.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Head, Body, Btn, Img } from '../../rows.js';
const initState = {
    rows: [
        { 'row': <Img /> },
        { 'row': <Body /> },
        { 'row': <Btn /> },
        { 'row': <Head /> }
    ] 
}
const rowReducer =  (state = initState, action) => {
    return state;
}
export default rowReducer;
```

### Query Reducer file

And here I meet my match.
I can update the initState with the payload, that's simple enough. But I can't get my head round how to use the payload to first index into the row array and then update the state with the retrieved array object. The final point of this is that for each payload that is delivered, the retrieved array object is added on to the end of the last. Thus building a new customised array.

Then I need only embed the array into the structures. Then whenever a structure is called. The user will have already defined which rows they would like in the structure and a completed module is rendered.

```
const initState = ''

const queryReducer =  (state = initState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'UPDATE_QUERY':
            console.log('/reducer');
            return action.payload
    }
    return state;
}
export default queryReducer
```

---

### ### Just incase you need to see it ###

Here is what the index file, the root reducer and one of the structure files look like. 
index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer.js';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Root reducer

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import rowReducer from './rowReducer.js'
import queryReducer from './queryReducer.js'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    rowReducer: rowReducer,
    queryReducer: queryReducer
});

export default rootReducer
```

A single column structure (ignore me indexing into the rows array in there.)

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      rows: state.rowReducer.rows
  }
}
class Single extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { rows } = this.props;
    return (
      <div style={{ fontSize: 0, lineHeight: 0 }}>
        <table id="Table1" cellSpacing={0} cellPadding={0} border={0} width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" align="center" style={{ borderCollapse: 'collapse', borderWidth: 0 }} bgcolor="#D9E1E2">
                <table className="Table2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellSpacing={0} cellPadding={0} border={0} width={680}>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style={{ paddingTop: 24, paddingBottom: 24 }} align="center">
                        <table className="Table3" align="center" cellSpacing={0} cellPadding={0} border={0} width={604}>
                          {rows[1].row}
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Single);
```

Comment: I wouldn't store pre-rendered JSX in redux.  It's works better if you store component names and props -- then in your connect or render method look up the component by it's name from a component registry.

Comment: I'm not following how you want to update the redux state.  Could you briefly describe the store before and after states and the nature of the action that modifies it?

Comment: @DougCoburn the initState of the queryReducer  is only a place holder right now. I'm envisioning building something very generally along the lines of `newRows: [{ 'row': { rows[payload].row } }]` into the state. To build a stored array of rows defined by the payloads that get actioned.